# Saving Image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, html5-video, href

I have an HTML page where I get video feed from device camera. I draw it to a canvas with a setTimeOut loop and take a picture to an image. Then I apply a filter to that image (sepia, grayscale...) and save it. The image is saved without the filter. Why isn't the filtered image saved but a "raw" one? I'm not that good at Javascript so please be gentle.

```
<video id = "video" autoplay></video>
<button onclick = "snap()">Snap</button>
<canvas id = "canvas" width = "400" height = "300"></canvas>
<img id = "photo" src = "pic.png" alt = "Photo">
<button onclick = "save()">Save</button>
<button onclick = "sepia()">Sepia</button>//Added in edit
//--------------
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var photo = document.getElementById('photo');

navigator.getMedia({ video: true, audio: false }, success, failure);
function success(stream) {
    video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
}
function failure(error) {}

video.addEventListener('play', sendToCanvas, false);
function sendToCanvas() {
    draw(this, context, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
function draw(video, context, width, height) {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height); 
    setTimeout(draw, 10, video, context, width, height); 
}
function snap() {
    photo.setAttribute('src', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
}
function save() {
    var currentdate = new Date().toLocaleString();
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = currentdate + ".png";
    link.href = photo.src;
    link.click();
}
function sepia() {//Added in edit
    photo.style["-webkit-filter"] = "sepia(100%)";
}
```

Comment: And how do you apply the filter? If by CSS, this is totally normal. You will have to apply it on the imageData you grab from `ctx.getImageData`. Styles applied on a canvas are not really drawn in the canvas and thus, not exportable by its methods.

Comment: I have a button for each filter with it's own function: function sepia() {
                photo.style["-webkit-filter"] = "sepia(100%)";}

Comment: So this is just CSS filter, re-read my comment, it's your answer

Comment: But I apply the filter to the Image and on the screen it is applied, just not saved.

Comment: Yes but it's like if you set background-color of the canvas, it's still not into the canvas' image, hence can't be exported.

Comment: I'm not getting it, sorry. I take a picture of the canvas and just leave it and then manipulate the image and save that. Image is it's own variable.

Comment: I posted an answer, I hope it will make things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using CSS filters, which are not really drawn into the canvas, but just a decoration from the page.

Hence, canvas' methods to extract its content won't keep these filters.

It's like if you do set a background-color to the canvas element without drawing anything, or some borders, you won't get these styles once you do use the `toDataURL` method, only the drawing made onto the canvas' context itself are parts of the canvas' content :

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
//only this black rectangle is drawn onto the canvas
ctx.fillRect(10,10,20,20);

expImg.src = c.toDataURL();
```

```css
/* these styles are only applied on the document,
   not onto the canvas itself
*/
canvas{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 10px solid red;
  }

img{
  border: 1px solid green;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<img id="expImg"/>
```

You have to understand the canvas is just like an image. When you do apply the CSS filters on it, you're not really modifying the file, but only its display in the document.

Now, you can process the filters directly onto the canvas' pixels, and be able to keep them.

Here is a small example showing you how to modify canvas pixels.

```js
var draw = function() {

  c.width = img.width;
  c.height = img.height;

  // first draw your image once
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  //then get its data
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  // get the array of pixels
  var arr = imgData.data;
  //loop through each pixels, 4 per loop because pixels are [R,G,B,A,R,G,B,A...]
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 4) {
    // store the red value
    var r = arr[i];
    //replace the green value with the red one
    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    arr[i + 1] = r;
  }
  // put the modified imageData back to your canvas
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
};

var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.onload = draw;

img.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1alt1303g9zpemd/UFBxY.png';
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Ps : it seems we will soon be able to directly set a context's [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) property, currently only available on FF, under a flag, but that will make things way easier !

Comment: Dammit. I thought there might be an easy way. Thanks for explaining it :)

Comment: Yep, that's not so easy, but note that there is a proposal for including css filter's directly on canvas drawings : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter But before it is adopted by browsers, you can check [this link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/) which provides a few filter operations.

Comment: @wantsToLearnAndroid Also, if this answer did solve your issue, or at least explained why it can't be solved, you can accept it so your question goes off the "in need of an answer" stream. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: And here's a link to a [sepia filter](https://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-effects-sepia/). :-)

Comment: Just tried FF with the flag changed to true and it works. Pretty cool :)

Comment: Yeah I discovered that yesterday and it's pretty neat. Also, this does mean that filters will finally be hardware accelerated ! Looking forward to a standardization.

Comment: Just tried out and the filters work on Chrome, Firefox and Opera when the flag is true. Hurey!